# How to .get() from Firebase to integrate in Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, discord.js

I'm a new JavaScript programmer facing a problem that I can't seem to solve. I'm trying to save data in a Cloud Firestore Database using Firebase and trying to save and take data from the database. I've successfully created saving data as per this code below:

```
db.collection("data").doc(message.author.id).set({
            "userID": message.author.id,
            "userName": message.author.tag,
            "userWallet": 500,
            "userItems": {
                "DogeCoin": 0,
                "TrollCoin": 0,
                "TrollTrophy": 0
            },
            "lastClaim": 0,
            "lastCrime": 0
        }).then(() => {
            message.channel.send(`${message.author.tag}, you have successfully created your account.`)
        })
```

While the saving part works the getting data part doesn't, I've tried a few methods but it still doesn't work. Right now, this is what I've worked on.

```
let wallet;
            let bank;
            db.collection("data").doc(message.author.id).get().then((q) => {
                if (q.exists){
                    wallet = q.data().userWallet;
                } else if(!q.exists){
                    message.channel.send(`${message.author.tag}, please go create an account.`)
                    return;
                }
            })
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Balance for ${message.author.tag}`)
            .setAuthor(`${client.user.tag}`)
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setDescription(`Created by ${client.user.tag}`)
            .addFields(
                    {name: "Bank", value: `${wallet}`}
            )
            .setImage("https://c.tenor.com/iQ7AzP7EgSAAAAAM/noice.gif")
            message.reply({embeds: [embed]})
            return;
```

I want to able to get the data from Firebase and use it in my code by showing it in an embed. Your help in sincerely appreciated. Thank you.

[image: An image to show the data saved in Firebase]

Comment: What doesn't work? Does an error get thrown?

Comment: I've worked on it. I've put the embed inside of the Promise Resolve code, specifically inside of the if command block. Thank you for your consideration